# ZVT protocol Reversal

Tags: terminal, payment

i'm using [this open source](https://github.com/areiter/libecterm) lib as a ZVT implementation.

I have problems with the reversal of older transactions. 
The example shows how to reverse the most recent transaction.

The [ZVT Protocol (p.40)](http://www.zvt-kassenschnittstelle.de/wp-content/uploads/PA00P015_13.07_en.pdf) says to send the following to the terminal:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBdYL.png)

tags in this brackets "[ ]" are optional.

I tried sending this:

```
06 30 06 12 34 5F 87 00 85   
06 30 = Reversal   
      06 = 6 bytes length
         12 34 5 = password with F as Filler?
                  87 = receipt no
                     00 85 = receipt no. 85
```

The password is: 12345
I dont know how to fill the empty space (uneven password). 0 and F does not work.
The receipt-no is a 2 byte long.

But the Terminal replies with error code "181" -> reversal not possible

my payment terminal is a iCT220.

Comment: In this project you can found some example to parse the zvt data https://github.com/Portalum/Portalum.Zvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to send

```
06 30 06 00 00 00 87 00 85
```

And watch out that `87` indicates the `receipt-no`. not the `trace-no`.